# replacing a hardcoded path

Tags: c#

`string antcbatchpath = @"""C:\Work\6.70_Extensions\release\SASE Lab Tools\ANT Builds\antc.bat"""`

in the above string, if i would like to replace `6.70_Extensions` with `buildStream` how do i do it?

`buildStream` can be `6.70_Extensions`, `7.00_Extensions` or `7.10.000_Tip` etc

`buildStream` is obtained from combobox selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you, I would do

```
string antcbatchpath = string.Format(@"""C:\Work\{0}\release\SASE Lab Tools\ANT Builds\antc.bat""", buildStream);
```

[string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx) is a highly useful method which I use all the time. To give credit where credit is due, I borrowed the link from Devendra's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
String antcbatchpath = @"""c:\work\{0}\release\SASE Lab Tools\ANT Builds\antc.bat""";

String newPath = String.Format(antcbatchpath, buildStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7.aspx),

```
 if (myComboBox.SelectedValue != null)
 {
     string buildStream = myComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();

     // Assuming your build stream is not culture dependent
     // {0} is the placement handler for the first argument
     string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"""C:\Work\{0}\release\SASE Lab Tools\ANT Builds\antc.bat""",
                      buildStream);
 }
```

Comment: You're close.  However, the original has 3 quotes in a row for a reason...  He's using it as a parameter to a process he's invoking in other steps.